# How to add navigation controller after designing the viewcontroller in Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10

I am building a hotel booking app in Xcode 10 with Swift 4, the design is complete in `viewController`  but unfortunately, I forgot to add `navigationController`. And so now I want to add the navigation controller without changing my design or at least having minimum damage in my design.

I already tried to add the `navigationController` after the design but somehow it is not working.

I want to add back or home navigation to my subviews. But right now when I am trying to add navigation controller it does not works properly let me just say when I run the app it's not showing any navigation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Click on your view on the interface builder. Then Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Answer (score -1):

Go to the app delegate file and type the following lines in the 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' block of code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyInitialViewController())

        return true
    }
```